# Why do retroviruses go through a DNA stage to replicate their RNA genome?

Tags: biochemistry, virology, retrovirus, reverse-transcription

Why do retroviruses (e.g.HIV) convert their RNA genome to DNA (using reverse transcriptase) and then transcribe it back into viral RNA (and translate that into viral proteins). Surely to replicate their genome it would be simpler to use RNA-dependent RNA polymerases as RNA viruses like Measles Virus do.

Comment: Biology isn't as stringent as [quantum physics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Totalitarian_principle), but still, "everything which is not forbidden is allowed." Retroviruses use reverse transcriptase because a) they can and b) it works. You can get into complex evolutionary arguments about comparative benefits, but ultimately retroviruses stick around because reverse transcriptase works well enough for them to continue to survive. Evolution isn't goal oriented - it doesn't seek simplicity just for simplicity's sake. What works, works, and what doesn't, doesn't.

Comment: I now feel my previous comments were based on a misunderstanding of the question. On this basis I have withdrawn them, answered the question, and reversed my close vote. The question is still very basic, but I can see how you might have become confused if the subject was not introduced to you properly.

Comment: I have changed your title and question to clarify  it as several people have been confused by it. If this is not what you meant could you please elaborate.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am going to focus the answer on mainly "why HIV virus has evolved such mechanisms to go from RNA to DNA and back to RNA when it could simply use the first RNA to make its copies". While others have already discussed the broad point, I will discuss more about the details. There are a few points which might support this, all of which basically come down to evolution.

- **Increased Mutations:** the process of conversion of viral RNA to DNA is carried out by the viral enzyme *reverse transcriptase*. The point here is that this process of reverse transcription is extremely error prone ([Zheng *et al*, 2005](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.imlet.2004.11.026)), which increase its chances of evolving drug resistance and other abilities.
- **Recombination:** again, the enzyme reverse transcriptase possesses ability to cause recombination of viral DNA. During recombination, the nascent DNA can switch multiple times between the two copies of the viral RNA ([Charpentier *et al*, 2006](https://doi.org/10.1128/JVI.80.5.2472-2482.2006)), known as copy-choice recombination, and can rapidly shuffle the genetic information between the parental and progeny genomes.
- **Post-transcriptional modifications:** after the viral DNA is completely transcribed, it undergoes splicing to form mature mRNA. These mRNAs lead to production of viral proteins *Tat* and *Rev*. Accumulationof Rev inside nucleus allowes the full mRNAs to leave the nucleus and form viral genomes or structural proteins *Gag* and *Env* ([Pollard *et al*, 1998](https://doi.org/10.1146/annurev.micro.52.1.491)). Thus, reverse transcription is vital for the virus.

**References:**

- [Zheng YH, Lovsin N, Peterlin BM (2005). "Newly identified host factors modulate HIV replication". *Immunol. Lett.* **97** (2): 225–34.](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.imlet.2004.11.026)
- [Charpentier C, Nora T, Tenaillon O, Clavel F, Hance AJ (2006). "Extensive recombination among human immunodeficiency virus type 1 quasispecies makes an important contribution to viral diversity in individual patients". *J. Virol.* **80** (5): 2472–82.](https://doi.org/10.1128/JVI.80.5.2472-2482.2006)
- [Pollard VW, Malim MH (1998). "The HIV-1 Rev protein". *Annu. Rev. Microbiol.* **52**: 491–532.](https://doi.org/10.1146/annurev.micro.52.1.491)

Comment: "extremely error prone (Zheng et al, 2005), which increase its chances..." - Do viruses - retroviruses -  have anything better, any proofreading at all? (cp. "what works, works")

Comment: I'll assume that "better" here means "better than other RNA viruses". In that case, I don't think so (I haven't looked into it, but coming from the observation that a lack of proofreading is somewhat beneficial for the virus, I think it's safe to deduce that the retroviruses would stay away from things like proofreading. Also, I doubt there would be quantitative studies regarding comparative analysis of proofreading activities of retroviruses and other RNA viruses).

Comment: Much later, from DNA back to RNA, there's none, I guess. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

**Interpreting the question**

Initially I interpreted the question as little more than “Why one type of virus rather than another?” (dsDNA. ssDNA, ssRNA [+ve v. –ve] etc.), and this (which would be unanswerable) was the way @Taimur seems to have understood it. And I also felt that the poster’s reference to ‘complexity’ reflected more his familiarity with other viruses than any real appreciation of what is complex in a molecular manner.

However I *now* think I misunderstood the question because of not appreciating the erroneous assumption on which I believe it is based. If I am correct, it could be rephrased in the following manner to make that assumption clear:

> “*If the only purpose of integrating a DNA copy of the retroviral RNA
>   into the host genome is to replicate the RNA in the virion*, why is an
>   RNA-dependent RNA polymerase not used as in other RNA viruses?"

**Answer**

> This stage of the retroviral life cycle in which a DNA copy is
>   integrated into the host genome is **not** an incidental stage in a
>   mechanism to replicate the virion RNA — *it is the key element of the
>   modus operandi or strategy of existence of the virus.*

**Explanation**

As explained in the first paragraph of the Wikipedia article on [retroviruses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Retrovirus), once integrated into the host genome it can persist there:

> “The host cell then treats the viral DNA as part of its own genome,
>   translating and transcribing the viral genes along with the cell's own
>   genes…”

One way of thinking of this is as a strategy the virus adopts for ‘hiding’ until circumstances are suitable for it to produce more infectious progeny. One might even regard the form that is integrated into the host DNA as the viral genome — rather than the form that is encapsulated by lipid and protein into virus particles.

This sort of lifestyle is similar in some ways to that of certain DNA bacteriophages that can produce either lytic or [lysogenic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lysogenic_cycle) infections. Such *persistence* of viral genomes in the host is also seen in some eukaryotic DNA viruses like [herpes simplex virus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Herpes_simplex_virus), in which an individual may have what is called a *latent* infection, which produces occurrences of cold sores (in the case of HSV1) throughout the lifetime of the individual as the virus is activated from time to time by various stimuli.

Comment: Is there some intermediate stage before the "DNA stage" where the virus is being translated from its RNA for presentation on MHC? Or, do cells have to wait, always? E.g. HIV Immune Evasion: Disruption of antigen presentation...Elizabeth R. Wonderlich et al. ("Perseverance is no evasion")

Comment: There is an excellent freely available account of reverse transciption here: https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3475395/pdf/cshperspectmed-HIV-a006882.pdf. From which you will see (Fig 1)that reverse transcription takes place on the viral RNA. I don't know whether there is sufficient enzyme in the virion to catalyse this — I imagine some translation has to occur, but this is not for providing a template for reverse transcription. I don't know what relevance presentation for MHC has to this, and in any case it is not an area I know anything about.

Answer (score 1):

Viruses are one of the particles whose evolutionary origin is still a mystery to scientists. Various hypotheses have been presented but none of them have been proven so far.

However, as one of our commenters has said, "What works, works and what doesn't, doesn't." This is the basic concept of the evolutionary theory. All organisms which can survive in an environment using a certain adaptation, whether it takes more time or less time, will survive and continue using the same adaptation.

One more point to consider is that individual organisms never evolve, only **populations (organisms of the same species living in the same area at the same time)** evolve. This means that a retro virus will **not** change to adapt to a simpler method just because it takes less time. If conditions arise that do not favour retroviral method of using reverse transcriptase but favours the method of other RNA viruses, then retroviruses will simply then decrease in number until they are zero and RNA viruses will survive.

I hope to have satisfactorily answered your inquiry.

Comment: Well, dude! You are not writing a letter. While we do expect formal language in questions and answers here, please don't post "overformal" answers.

Comment: @another'Homosapien' I will make sure to avoid that next time. Thank you.

Comment: @another'Homosapien' I have made the edits.